# Cannot write files on mounted volume aws efs

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-ecs, mount

I'm building a scalable and distributed architecture for workflows within our company by leveraging the use of Apache Airflow. I'm using ECS Fargate.

Since this is a distributed architecture, a non-centralized file system is required in order to have a consistent-shared view across all machines (ie, the webserver needs to access the DAGs files, scheduler, and workers also).

For such purpose, I'm using AWS EFS, I can successfully mount the file system into an EC2 instance, but I'm unable to write or create a file within it.

This is the policy attached to the fs:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleSatement01",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXX:file-system/fs-aaaaaaa"
        }
    ]
}
```

and as the doc says:

> elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite  ------> Provides an NFS client with
> write permissions on a file system.

I'm mounting by executing the following command:

```
 sudo mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=fsap-oooooooooooooooo fs-aaaaaaa:/ efs
```

and indeed, I can see the content, but got `Permission denied` every time I try to write.

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ sudo mount -t efs -o tls,accesspoint=fsap-oooooooooooooooo fs-aaaaaaa:/ efs
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G  616K  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  2.7G  5.4G  33% /
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/0
127.0.0.1:/     8.0E     0  8.0E   0% /home/ec2-user/efs
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX ~]$ cd efs/
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX efs]$ touch a
touch: cannot touch ‘a’: Permission denied
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX efs]$
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX efs]$ sudo touch a
touch: cannot touch ‘a’: Permission denied
[ec2-user@ip-XXXX efs]$ sudo su -
Last login: Wed Aug 19 21:29:39 UTC 2020 on pts/0
[root@ip-XXXX ~]#
[root@ip-XXXX ~]# cd /home/ec2-user/efs/
[root@ip-XXXX efs]#
[root@ip-XXXX efs]# touch d
touch: cannot touch ‘d’: Permission denied
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it possible that the ec2-user do not have permission to write. did you try writing as sudo ?

Comment: did you try to get yourself read permissions as well? may be something to try

Comment: In the end, I could create/touch a file by removing entirely the file system policy and being ``root`` user. in the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully achieved the goal, and this answer is intended to share my experience just in case someone bumps into the same use case.

If you are using ECS Fargate, there is an option to mount volumes in the version with platform 1.4.0. So, within `container_definitions` there is an option called `mountPoints`:

```
    ...
    "entryPoint": [],
    "command": [],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": ${host_port},
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": ${container_port}
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume": "dags",
        "containerPath": "/usr/local/airflow/dags",
        "readOnly": false
      }
    ],
    "cpu": ${cpu},
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_HOST",
        "value": "${postgres_host}"
      },
      {
        "name": "AIRFLOW_COMPONENT",
        "value": "webserver"
      },
      {
        "name": "REDIS_HOST",
        "value": "${redis_host}"
      }
    ]
    ...
```

that will mount the EFS volume. Remember to specify the `volume` configuration. Here's the terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition_airflow_webserver" {
  family                    = "airflow-webserver"
  requires_compatibilities  = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode              = "awsvpc"
  execution_role_arn        = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_service_role_airflow_webserver.arn}"
  container_definitions     = "${data.template_file.airflow_webserver.rendered}"
  cpu                       = 1024
  memory                    = 2048

  volume {
    name = "dags"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = "${aws_efs_file_system.airflow_dags_efs.id}"
      root_directory          = "/"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if there's something ambiguous or unclear.

Comment: can you tell me what the `containerPath` means? I am unable to write to the volume and I'm not sure how this path should be set. I have `root_directory="/"` but I want my app (grafana) to write to a few directories inside the volume

Comment: containerPath is the path from the container's viewpoint where the EFS mountpoint is located. Assume you were in the container's terminal then "/usr/local/airflow/dags" directory would actually be EFS's "/" directory.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. The solution that worked for me was two steps

1. Add `elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess` to the action statement of the policy. For example,

   ```
       "Action": [
           "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
           "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
           "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"
       ],
   ```
2. Then, after mounting the EFS, change it's permissions to allow writing. For example if I mounted to `/efs/data`, then

   ```
   cd /efs/data
   sudo chmod 775 /efs/data
   ```

And now it works.

If you want to avoid step 2, you can go into the AWS "Access Point" settings and update the "POSIX User" and "Root directory creation permissions" to be your user/group IDs. For example, in ubuntu the default user usually has a POSIX ID of "1000" and a group ID of "1000".

To find out your user ID,

```
 id -u <username>
```

To find out your group ID,

```
 id -g <username>
```

Comment: AWS support just responded to my case on this subject. They confirmed this issue and pointed out that in order to prevent `ClientRootAccess` by default and still have write access for some connections, you'll need to follow the instructions in this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/enable-root-squashing.html. It involves creating a specific IAM role.